# matplotlib: non tabular subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib

I can easily create subplots in matplotlib using something like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2)
```

However, what I would like to do is something where I have two plots in the first row and one plot (which takes the width of the two plots above) in the second row. Is it somehow possible to do that with matplotlib?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this page: http://matplotlib.org/users/gridspec.html

It looks like the syntax you are after is

```
plt.subplot2grid((3,3), (1, 0), colspan=2)
```